# Prove that $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1\\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some help with this one.

Let $A \in M_{2×2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue $λ$, with $\gamma(\lambda)=1$,

then $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\ 
0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}$.

Here is what I know so far:

The geometric multiplicity of $λ$ is $1$, then we have one eigenvector, let's say $\Bbb v$.

We can maybe take another vector, $\Bbb v_1$, such that $(\Bbb {v,v_1})$ is a basis.

I do not know Jordan form, and I do know theorems like Cayley-Hamilton, if that helps.

Thanks a lot, I appreciate your time!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128837/discussion-on-question-by-calculuslover-prove-that-a-is-similar-to-beginbma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, start with your eigenvector $v$. Then take a second vector $w$ to get a basis $\{v, w\}$. We have $Av = \lambda v$ and $Aw = xv + yw$ for some unknown scalars $x, y$. Thus, with respect to this basis, we have

$$[A] = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & x \\ 0 & y \end{bmatrix}$$

A common principle here is that because $y$ is on the diagonal like this, $A - y \mathrm{Id}$ is singular. So $y$ is an eigenvalue, which means $y = \lambda$. Thus

$$[A] = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & x \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$$

And now it's just a matter of playing around with things to get $x = 1$. Well first, can you see that $x \neq 0$ given these hypotheses?

Then the next step is to just kind of play around with a change of basis: $\{v, av + bw\}$ until you can get $x = 1$. Try simple cases like $b = 1$ or $a = 0$ first.

Edit: use a computer algebra system if it helps:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & x \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \;?$$

Comment: Thank you, that helps! Can you explain why is this one true: $Aw=xv+yw$ ?

Comment: @CalculusLover Since $v, w$ is a basis, $Aw$ can be written in terms of that basis with some coefficients $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! Appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

Outline: Pick any $\mathbf v_1\neq 0$ which is **not** an eigenvector.

Let $\mathbf v_2=A \mathbf v_1-\lambda \mathbf v_1$ Show $\mathbf v_2$ **is** an eigenvector and that $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2$ are a basis.

Then consider how $A$ acts on that basis:

$$\begin{align}A \mathbf v_1&=\lambda \mathbf v_1+ \mathbf v_2\\A \mathbf v_2&=0 \mathbf v_1+\lambda \mathbf v_2\end{align}$$

Then $S=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf v_2&\mathbf v_1\end{pmatrix}$ satisfies:

$$S^{-1}AS=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why the two equations gives us what $S^{-1}AS$ is

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gamma(\lambda) = 1$, it follows that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(t) = (t-\lambda)^2$, hence thanks to Jordan canonical form theory, $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I do not know what Jordan form is...